# angular nvd3 piechart not rendering data from backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using angular d3 directive to render a pie chart from backend data. 
Pie chart works for static data:

```
$http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : piechart_url,
    headers:{
    'Content-Type' :'application/json'
}})
.success(function(resp,status,headers,config) {
    //try hard coded here
    $scope.exampleData = [
           { key: "One", y: 5 },
           { key: "Two", y: 2 },
           { key: "Seven", y: 9 }
    ];
})
```

But it does not work with the data from a backend API. 
*** It only renders first key in the pie chart. ***

```
$http({
   method : 'GET',
   url : piechart_url,
   headers:{
     'Content-Type' :'application/json'
   }})
   .success(function(resp,status,headers,config) {
      $scope.exampleData = resp.items;
   })
```

The resp.items contains

```
   [{"key":"ONE","y":10000},{"key":"TWO","y":10}]
```

I have tried adding/removing quotes.

Comment: Have you looked into the developer console for errors? Maybe you could provide a plunker.